# Android - Dynamic TableLayout not Working

Tags: android, layout, dynamic, rows, tablelayout

I have a problem, I can't create a dynamic table layout using code.
It is giving me a error while opening the application in my Android Device. Does anyone knows the problem? The compile goes fine... but on running it may be throwing some exception..

Can someone help me?

Here is the code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        android.widget.TableLayout.LayoutParams params = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
        TextView tv2=new TextView(this);
        tv1.setLayoutParams(params);
        tv2.setLayoutParams(params);
        tv1.setText("Hello1!");
        tv2.setText("Hello2!");
        TableLayout layoutINNER = new TableLayout(this);
        layoutINNER.setLayoutParams(params);
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        tr.setLayoutParams(params);
        tr.addView(tv1);
        tr.addView(tv2);
        layoutINNER.addView(tr);

        LinearLayout main = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.android_main_layout);
        main.addView(layoutINNER);


        setContentView(main);
}
```

And here is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/android:main_layout"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
</LinearLayout>
```

Does anyone know the reason? I guess its everything fine.. no?
Thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind... the problem was here:

setContentView(main);

I can't do that, I need to using some layout from R.layout... not R.id lol
Thank you anyways !

Answer (score -1):

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) //Then cast the view
LinearLayout main = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.android_main_layout);
```

Then lastly add this code `main.addView(layoutINNER)`